# how to compare list string parameters in a function with login input(name,pass)?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm building a project with asp.net and I'm new with this.
I created a list that each value has 2 strings in my controller. I want to build a login page that will check if the strings in the login page input(name,password) are equal to the ones in the list(I'm trying to create login without db).in my model I already wrote a class with string password and name. 
how do I add a function in my controller with the list and compare the parameters to the input of the user?

any help will be appreciated. thank you.

Controller

```
static List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> users = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>
        {
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("dennis", "pass"),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("kap", "111111")
            // how to search in a list
        };
```

Model

```
   public class Login
    {
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "שם משתמש")]
        public string userName { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "סיסמא")]
        public string userPass { get; set; }


    }
```

Comment: Would it not be easier to use a `Dictionary<string, string>`? Then you can add to the dictionary with `users.Add("dennis", "pass");`

Comment: `Dictionary<string,string>` may make this easier than using a list of key value pairs. Dictionary provides a `.ContainsKey` method as well as indexing by the key.

Comment: @AlfieGoodacre i am learning, thanks

Comment: Also, if anyone other than yourself has even the possibility of using this website, **hash the passwords**

Comment: @KelsonBall sure, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is working code you can try on https://dotnetfiddle.net/.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic; 
using System.Linq; 

public class Program
{
    public class Login
    {
        public string userName { get; set; }
        public string userPass { get; set; }
    }

    static List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> users = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>
        {
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("dennis", "pass"),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("kap", "111111")
        };

    public static void Main()
    {
        Login testLogin = new Login();
        testLogin.userName = "dennis";
        testLogin.userPass = "pass";    
        bool isValidUser = users.Any(user => user.Key == testLogin.userName && user.Value == testLogin.userPass ); 
        Console.WriteLine(isValidUser );
    }
}
```

As a side note, to me, it would be more intuitive to have a 'LoginInformation' object with a username and password field. Also, I am assuming you understand that what you are doing is absolutely not secure. Passwords must be hashed and salted.

Edit: Here is the code with the check moved out into its own method:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic; 
using System.Linq; 

public class Program
{
    public class Login
    {
        public string userName { get; set; }
        public string userPass { get; set; }

        public bool isUserNameValid(string userName, string userPass, List< KeyValuePair<string, string> > validUsers) 
        {
            return validUsers.Any(user => user.Key == userName && user.Value == userPass ); 
        }
    }

    static List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> users = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>
        {
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("dennis", "pass"),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("kap", "111111")
        };

    public static void Main()
    {   Login login = new Login(); 
        bool isValidUser = login.isUserNameValid("dennis", "pass", users); 
        Console.WriteLine(isValidUser);
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks I will try now! all this I need to write only in the model right?

Comment: Np. I don't understand the question though. You should be able to copy and paste the code above into jsfiddle, and it should "just work". The line that's relevant to you start with "isValidUser" - that's where the check occurs. You can move that out into a separate function if you want. You can do that check wherever you receive the login information in the actual code.

Comment: can we talk in the chat please?

Comment: Yes, sure. //comment length

Comment: can you send a request? I can't

Answer (score 0):

How about something along the lines of

```
if (users.Where(kvp => kvp.Key == userName && kvp.Value == userPAss).Any())
    LoginOK();
```

PS: A login without a db can be tricky. If all login information is stored in memory, all user logins will be deleted if the site has to restart.

Comment: Side note, this requires `using System.Linq` on the off chance it's not already in

Comment: thanks you! yes I know it will be deleted its an assignment for a job, they said without db

Comment: how to insert the parameters in the actionResult function?

Comment: "Where" is a poor choice here, since ".Any" exists.